# Magento shop gets stuck on billing informtaion

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

After years of it working fine, our website has stopped functioning correctly. Currently it works well until a user tries to checkout. Upon clicking continue on the billing information the page doesn't respond and users cannot continue their purchase.

I have tried adding a blank `<div class="col-right"></div>` in onepage.phtml as suggested in another post with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, which was resolved by disabling the magento compiler in the admin panel. Check you haven't got this enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the Javascript error in that page;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'corner'
```

And then take it from there. Comment out his line - `$j(".mega_content").corner("5px bottom");`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I fixed this issue and still getting the same problem